# Databricks SQL doesn't support DECLARE keyword

Tags: sql, databricks

In SQL we can use DECLARE to initialise a value

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01/01/2013'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '01/01/2015'
```

As DATABRICKS SQL doesn't support DECLARE how can we write the same code in DATABRICKS sql?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion here, there is no support for TSQL style declarations in databricks SQL.

https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001c9RUYCA2/whats-the-equivalent-of-declare-in-databricks-sql-

May be for your situation you may need to handle those variables in your client code or in middle layers.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks SQL doesn't support TSQL, if needed you can make use of parameters in your query

https://docs.databricks.com/sql/user/queries/query-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use parameters in a DECLARE style in Databricks SQL.
Read all about this in here:

[Dynamic SQL in Databricks Notebooks — using SQL](https://medium.com/p/7fe9aca4d767)